# What's the correct way in C# to expand latin ligature graphenes (like œ) to its component characters in UTF-8 space (oe)?

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

I have a use case where strings containing latin ligatures, like œ or æ, as well as its diacritics, require translation to their expanded counterparts available under UTF-8 character space. In this scenario, the unicode character `æ` (U+00E6) and diacritic variants like `æ̃`, `ǽ` and `ǣ` should be replaced with `ae`; capitalization should also be respected.

A naive solution could be implemented using a static translation structure of some sort, but that feels brittle and not sustainable in the long term.

So what would be the recommended, correct way to implement this string translation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoderfallback?view=net-6.0

Comment: What you are asking for has nothing to do with UTF encodings, it has to do with Normalization and Transliteration instead.